# Firebug console keeps printing postmessage message type required

Tags: console, firefox-addon, firebug

I use Firebug to test CSS, Sizzle and Xpath selectors, so I can use them in Selenium.
In every selector I test, I get the message `postmessage message type required`.
What does it mean, and can i get rid of it?
I am using Firefox 26 and Firebug 1.12.5.
In the Firebug console i type for example 
`$$("button#gbqfba")` eg. for Google page, and the element is highlighted.
This is used to be done without popping the postmessage.

Comment: Which version of Firefox? Which version of Firebug? How do you test the selectors? Where do you get that error message?

Comment: You need to add more details, like a URL to see the errors.